# How to read CSV file containing Chinese characters?

Tags: r, csv, character-encoding

My computer's information is as follows,

```
 > sessionInfo()
  R version 3.3.1 (2016-06-21)
  Platform: x86_64-apple-darwin13.4.0 (64-bit)
  Running under: OS X 10.11.5 (El Capitan)

  locale:
  [1] zh_CN.UTF-8/zh_CN.UTF-8/zh_CN.UTF-8/C/zh_CN.UTF-8/zh_CN.UTF-8

  attached base packages:
  [1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base     

  loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
  [1] tools_3.3.1
```

I want to read a csv file into my Rstudio by

```
dat <- read.csv("e.csv", fileEcoding = "utf-8")
```

The CSV file is like this,

[image]

And I got an error,

```
> dat
  postal_code province
1          10        p
```

The result is just a 1*2 data frame.

Comment: how can we help if we don't have access to your data!!!! please provide an actual reproducible example. An image file doesn't cut it!

Comment: you means I need to upload the csv file?

Comment: You could create the csv within your example script like I did in my answer. That would be best. But if not that then uploading it would be better than nothing. http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: @Hack-R Yes, if I input the data.frame into Rstudio by my hands containing Chinese character, my computer could display correctly. But when I want to read a csv file into Rstudio, it got an error. BTW, how can I upload the raw data? I have tried a lot, but still can't find the solution. Thank you!

Comment: You can use `dput` in R to produce a version of the data which you can copy and paste to StackOverflow. Alternately you could upload your .csv to a site like GitHub.com or Google Drive and provide a link.

Answer (score 2):

```
chinese <- data.frame(Postal=c(10,20,30),Province=c('中','華','民族'))
write.csv(chinese, "chinese.csv",row.names = F)

dat <- read.csv("chinese.csv")
dat # Here it is in Unicode
```

> ```
>   Postal         Province
> 1     10         <U+4E2D>
> 2     20         <U+83EF>
> 3     30 <U+6C11><U+65CF>
> ```

If you still have trouble please provide your data and we can help further.

Another related example:

```
x=c('中華民族');x; y <- data.frame(x, stringsAsFactors=FALSE) 
y
```

> ```
>                                  x
> 1 <U+4E2D><U+83EF><U+6C11><U+65CF>
> ```

```
x
```

> [1] "中華民族"

Comment: I cannot repeat your answer.`Error in source("~/.active-rstudio-document", encoding = "UTF-8", echo = TRUE) : 
  ~/.active-rstudio-document:13:6: unexpected INCOMPLETE_STRING
12: 
13: x<-c('
         ^
In addition: Warning message:
In readLines(file, warn = FALSE) :
  invalid input found on input connection '~/.active-rstudio-document'`